# Formatting output from mysql (array of values)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am running a sql query to output value of field, which has array of values. How can I format those value using php/css/html.

This is the output I get from following code:

```
$rb = $wpdb->get_results("select value 
                          from wp_rg_lead_detail 
                          where field_number = 33 
                            and lead_id = 
                                 (select distinct lead_id 
                                  from wp_rg_lead_detail 
                                  where value = '".$uname."')
                         "); 
foreach( $rb as $r){ 
    echo $r->value . "<br/> "; 
}
```

MySQL Output Value:

```
a:2:{
    i:0;a:2:{s:10:"First Name";s:6:"testb1";s:9:"Last Name";s:5:"test1";}
    i:1;a:2:{s:10:"First Name";s:6:"testb2";s:9:"Last Name";s:5:"test2";}
    }
```

Desired Output:

```
 FirstName      LastName 
 testb1         test1
 testb2         test2
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: That looks like you seralized it. `print_r` and `var_dump` are good ways to look at what is inside an array.

Comment: that's json, not mysql output. if you're just going to be tearing apart the json to display it, then there's no point in json-encoding the mysql results to begin with (unless you're doing this in client-side JS code or something).

Comment: @MarcB that's not JSON. It looks like output from `seralize()`, not `json_encode()`

Comment: This is the output I get from following code:

$rb = $wpdb->get_results("select value from wp_rg_lead_detail where field_number = 33 and lead_id = (select distinct lead_id from wp_rg_lead_detail where value = '".$uname."')");
 
 foreach( $rb as $r){
    echo $r->value . "<br/> ";
 }

Comment: whoops, right. yeah, that's serialize. either way... no point in serializing if you just need to yank it apart again right away.

Comment: That output does not look like valid JSON or valid PHP serialize() data either.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you'll need to remove the new lines and tabs from your serialized data before it will `unserialize()` correctly:

```
$data = unserialize('a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"First Name";s:6:"testb1";s:9:"Last Name";s:5:"test1";}i:1;a:2:{s:10:"First Name";s:6:"testb2";s:9:"Last Name";s:5:"test2";}}');
```

---

You can output the results you want with a simple loop like this:

```
// Keep track of whether the headers have been output yet
$headersOutput = false;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // If the headers haven't been output yet
    if (!$headersOutput) {
        // Output the headers only
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)), PHP_EOL;
        // Update variable so it won't happen again
        $headersOutput = true;
    }
    // Output the values
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Example:](https://eval.in/317985)

```
First Name  Last Name
testb1  test1
testb2  test2
```

You can swap the `"\t"` tab characters for whatever you want to delimit columns with, and swap `PHP_EOL` for what should delimit new lines.

If you want to add this data to an array (e.g. to write to a CSV instead) then just use `$output[] = implode...` instead of `echo` and use `$output` at the end.